# projectRaster() function in R: Increase vs decrease output resolution

Tags: r, resolution, r-raster

As I'm not too familiar working with raster. Under the output resolution argument, let's say I currently have it at 100. If I decrease the number to 50, then I have just doubled the resolution. And similarly if I increased the number to 200, then I decreased the resolution.

Can someone verify this so that I am understanding this correctly?

Comment: That’s right. Resolution on this context means the resolution (size) of each cell on your raster. So resolution = 1 means that your cells are 1x1. If you change it  to 2 you are reducing the number of cells (four 1x1 cells = 1 2x2 cell). Since the extent of the raster does not change higher "resolution" of the cell means less cells, that decrease the perceived "resolution" of the raster image. Hope it is clear enough

Comment: Check this link, it is well explained there https://www.neonscience.org/resources/learning-hub/tutorials/raster-res-extent-pixels-r#jump-2

Comment: Great explanation. That makes sense